# How to search by pattern in thunar

Tags: files, search, thunar

In Thunar it is possible to open a small search box by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> but when you type in something the results seem to take into account only the first letters of the filename. If you search for words that are in the middle of the filename nothing happens.

Example:

- file-1.php
- my-file.txt
- another-one.js

If I type in `f` then `file-1.php` gets highlighted but if I type in `one` nothing happens. I'd expect the file containing the letters `one`  to be the only one showing up, or at least highlighted.

I know there is catfish and I routinely use it, even by launching it from the folder's custom action, which is very handy, but even better would be to have an improved search functionality, just similar to the one found in MAC OS.

Is there anything in the Linux world close to what I described?
Thanks!

**UPDATE** Nautilus does exactly what I described

Comment: There is something like FZF: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf - You can configure it to search in a list of files and directories. Personally I use it only to search through the bash history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> functions as typeahead search, what you are looking for already exists in thunar,
Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> then you can search by a pattern:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+B hides the side panel in my Thunar (Ubuntu Studio, Thunar 1.6.15), Ctrl+S does indeed what I was searching for, thanks so much! Unfortunately it seems to work just on some files, please check the screencast: https://youtu.be/qRPnv187i44

Comment: @Nicola I meant Ctrl+F, the search is case sensitive so search for "Scorpions".

Comment: it works. Hopefully they'll implement case-insensitive search

Comment: This is not the same thing at all : 1-It's case-sensitive (now that's user-hostile) and 2- it *selects* the matching line(s) (and not even focusing on the first!??) not allowing you to cycle though them ; So it's basically **not at all** the feature the OP is talking about. Thunar is so good, why they wouldn't implement a sane, non-modal search (just type some chars and use the arrow keys to cycle candidates) is really beyond me, and is the **only** thing keeping me from using it.